# Is there any way to have a number of video feeds cycle in rotation with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Is there any way I could take, lets say, 4 live video streams and have them cycle in a rotation on the screen? I want to take a video feed and play, wait for 5 seconds, go to next video feed, wait 5 seconds, etc...Below is the actual `ffmpeg` command I want to use and the only idea I have thus far is:

```
for rotation in $source4 $source5 $source6 $source7; do
    ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 100 -i $source1\
           -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 100 -i $source2\
           -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 100 -i $source3\
           -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 100 -i $rotation\
           -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=3840x2160 [base];\
           [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [upperleft];\
           [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [upperright];\
           [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [lowerleft];\
           [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [lowerright];\
           [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];\
           [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920 [tmp2];\
           [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=1080 [tmp3];\
           [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1920:y=1080"\
           -c:v h264_nvenc -preset llhq -f matroska - | ffplay -
           sleep 5
    done
```

As you can see, this would not be very efficient or even usable considering how long it takes to get everything going. If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it. I am only fluent in Linux shell scripting (Bash) so any other language would be out of my reach at this time. I am defiantly open to suggestions for other tools or frameworks to try. The main goal is to make a script for a group of security cameras with one in the mosaic that rotates through all the additional camera feeds that do not include the 3 already on the screen. It needs to be as low maintenance as possible i.e. a network issue drops connection it should automatically keep checking for connectivity and restart when established. I can do this in a Bash script very easily but getting the videos all up on screen is been a challenge. I considered making completely separate invocations of `ffplay` for each feed then using `wmctrl` or similar to arrange them on screen but I am still left with the issue of restarting the rotating one all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Cycle infinite:

```
#!/bin/bash
INP=("input 1.mp4" test01.mkv test02.mkv test03.mkv)
while true; do
  for i in "${INP[@]}"; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v h264_nvenc -t 5 -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -
  done
done
```

Maybe, better way is launch every input separately and play with `wmctrl`